# RestTemplate POST - handle response

Tags: java, spring, post, resttemplate, basic-authentication

I am aware of the similar posts and i checked them, but non of them could help me.

I want to POST to a API (that manages for examples tasks) that requires three parameters and a basic auth.
In postman it works. I provide the body like:

```
{
    "title": "foo",
    "description": "bar",
    "completed": "false"
}
```

and set the basic auth (with username and password). The API sends a response like this:

```
{
  "id": 0001
}
```

Everything works fine if i send a POST to the api, but now i want to implement it in java. I am getting a 400 bad request if i try to send a POST: HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request (DefaultResponseErrorHandler). The Task and TaskResponse are pojo's with the fields like in the request and response and a no-arg/full-arg constructor, getter and setter.

```
 Task task = new Task("foo", "bar", false);
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<Task> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(task, createHttpHeader());
        ResponseEntity<TaskResponse> result = template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, TaskResponse.class);

private HttpHeaders createHttpHeader() {
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        requestHeaders.set("Authorization", createBasicAuthHeaderValue(username, password));
        return requestHeaders;
    }

    private String createBasicAuthHeaderValue(String username, String password) {
        String credentials = username + ":" + password;
        byte[] base64Credentials = Base64.encodeBase64(credentials.getBytes());
        return "Basic " + Arrays.toString(base64Credentials);
    }
```

Comment: I tried different things, but i nothing works for me. From my point of view the problem is how to react to the response, because it is for example not the request, that comes back as response. It is something totally different. In this example the id of the created task. I tried to use String.class as response-type, but it is not working.

Comment: Have you included Jackson in class path and you can enable trace mode and verify if the request body has correct Json representation.

Comment: @Bhokal What is Jackson for? I am wondering...because the response is just a JSON. Shouldn't String.class work for me?

Comment: I enabled trace mode and it has the class name in front. Is that correct? Normally it is of cause just the braces and the fields. `Writing [Task{title='foo', description='bar', completed='false'}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@5a12c728]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered, that this implementation is fine. It accepts String as a Response type. There was another problem, but not related to this context.